# Can I catch a throw exception from method?

Tags: java, exception, methods, try-catch, throws

When I try to throw an exception from method declaration I get the error "Unreachable catch block for ClassNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body".

The code is this:

```
public class MenuSQL {
    private static String sentence = "";
    private static int option;
    Statement sentenceSQL = ConnectSQL.getConexion().createStatement();

public MenuSQL(int option) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    super();
    this.option = option;
    try {
        System.out.print("Introduce the sentence: ");
        System.out.print(sentence);
        sentence += new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        System.out.println(MenuSentence.rightNow("LOG") + "Sentence: " + sentence);

        if (opcion == 4) {
            MenuSentence.list(sentence);
        } else {
            sentenceSQL.executeQuery(sentence);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(MenuSentence.rightNow("SQL") + "Sentence: " + sentence);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(MenuSentence.rightNow("ERROR") + "Sentence: " + sentence);
    }
}
}
```

How can I catch `ClassNotFoundException`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to catch an exception that can never be thrown in your `try`block? And why does your method throw the exception althouh it catches them?

Comment: There's simply no point within the method that a ClassNotFoundException could be thrown.

Comment: It's because compiler force me to throw that Exception in method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch block of a `try{...} catch(){...}` statement can only catch exceptions thrown by the `try{...}` block. (Or a superclass of that exception)

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt("1");
    //Integer.parseInt throws NumberFormatException
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //Handle this error
}
```

However, what you are trying to do is basically this:

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt("1");
    //Integer.parseInt throws NumberFormatException
} catch (OtherException e) {
    //Handle this error
}
```

Because none of the statements in your `try{...}` block throw `OtherException`, the compiler will give you an error, because it knows that **nothing** in your `try{...}` block will **ever** throw that exception, so you should not try to `catch` something that is never `thrown`.

In your case, nothing in your `try{...}` block throws a `ClassNotFoundException`, so you don't need to catch it. You can remove the `catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {...}` from your code to fix the error.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your info is very useful.